# Odoo10 strange warning

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

This is my code.

```
<span t-esc="o.amount_total * (o.type in 'out_refund' and -1 or 1)" t-esc-options='{"widget": monetary, "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
```

in Odoo10 i'm getting this warning

```
WARNING db odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.ir_qweb: Use new syntax for '<span t-esc="o.amount_total * (o.type in 'out_refund' and -1 or 1)" t-tag="span"/>
widget monetary
            ' monetary widget t-options (python dict instead of deprecated JSON syntax).
```

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.

Problem is you are giving options as json. but you need to pass it as python dictionary.

```
<span t-esc="o.amount_total * (o.type in 'out_refund' and -1 or 1)" t-esc-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': o.currency_id}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving JSON values directly try to covert as list or dictionary as python forma